# How do I get specific xml layouts for specific phone screens in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, layout, size

So I'm creating different xml files for different phone screens in Android Studio.
I tried a number of methods for creating xml for different screens.

The first one was 4 folders layout-small, large, normal and xlarge it worked for the big tablet screens except for Nexus one of size 480 x 800.

so I created a folder called layout-w320dp and it worked but it overrided my large and xlarge xml files.
As in when ever I click for tablet screens it brings up the w320dp xml file instead of the xml in large and xlarge folders.

So I created the other folders w480dp, w600dp, w720dp but using xml files messes up everything but if I don't use a xml from these folders it assigns the w320dp one to the tablet screens.

[image]

My toolbar for phone screens and xml is like this. It's assigning ones I don't want to phone screens. How can I override it and say for example this xml has to match with this specific phone screen size? Right now it's using XML and trying to fit it to a phone size that messes up everything.

Is there a way to assign a specific xml to a specific phone without it doing it for other phones?

Comment: "It's assigning ones I don't want to phone screens" -- like what? The roster in your screenshot seems reasonable, for devices held in portrait. Bear in mind that `-w...dp` qualifiers are for "current width" or "available width", which takes into account portrait versus landscape. "How can I override it and say for example this xml has to match with this specific phone screen size?" -- you don't. "Is there a way to assign a specific xml to a specific phone without it doing it for other phones?" -- no.

Comment: My layout works for 5.5inch phone screens (pixel XL) since I did the xml for that one but it would be cut of in the nexus 4 (4.7in) and nexus 5 (5inch). They both use the w320dp xml file layout. I don't really want to convert the 5.5inch layout down to a xml that works for 3 devices since it looks perfect for the 5.5inch phone screens.

Comment: "but it would be cut of in the nexus 4 (4.7in) and nexus 5 (5inch)" -- then fix the layout. If you do not know how to fix the layout, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] showing your layout plus screenshots of where the problems arise. It should be possible to create one layout that works across this very tiny range of screen sizes.